# return $.extend and this in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm working on a component architectural project and I saw this piece of code.

```
clone : function() {
    return $.extend(true, {}, this);
}
```

What does this even means? Pass `this` into an object using `$.extend`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `clone` is a method of an object that simply creates a clone of the original object. You could say it's a way to create a real copy of an object, not just a reference to it. So `this` refers to the object the method belongs to.

```js
var obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  clone: function() {
    return $.extend(true, {}, this);
  }
};

var clone = obj.clone();

obj.one = "one";

console.log(obj);
console.log(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's strange, isn't there already a clone() method in jquery, why use $.extend

Comment: As far as I understand jQuery `jquery.clone()` is only used to clone HTML elements (optionally with data and events), and not plain javascript objects. The code snippet you provided does not show what the `clone()` method belongs to. jQuery docs: The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all of their descendant elements and text nodes.

Comment: Some more: native javascript objects don't have a clone method. And when you wrap a plain object in the jQquery $ function and try to call `.clone()` on it you get a `TypeError: elem.cloneNode is not a function
`. So `$.extend()` is the jQuery way to make a real copy of a plain javascript object.

Comment: You should add a link to [jQuery's extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and mention it can do shallow and deep copy.